# Por que utilizar duas linguagens server-side no mesmo sistema?

Tags: python, node.js, característica-linguagem, lado-do-servidor

**Por que eu vejo muitos sistemas com duas, até três linguagens de programação?**

Quando eu vejo um sistema que migra de uma linguagem pra outra, eu até compreendo, mas por que muitos mantém duas ou três linguagens de programação?

Por exemplo, eu ja vi gente falando de empresa que utiliza Python e Node.js.

**O que o Python faz que o Node.js não faz?**

Claro, eu sei a diferença entre as duas linguagens, mas no âmbito geral, é quase a mesma coisa.

*OBS: Eu entendo claramente os motivos óbvios de se utilizar client-side como JavaScript (jQuery) e Python no server-side.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essas decisões normalmente ocorrem mais pelo motivo que já identificou. Começaram com uma tecnologia e identificaram que outra poderia ser mais útil para algumas tarefas. E é comum não dar para fazer a migração de tudo. Em geral não é nem pela linguagem, o que neste caso nem poderia ser mesmo, já que Node.js sequer é uma linguagem de programação.

Na maioria dos casos encontraram alguma biblioteca ou alguma coisa pronta usando uma tecnologia diferente da que estavam usando e acham que é mais fácil usar aquilo e arcar com a integração entre as tecnologias do que fazer algo próprio, ou portar o que existia em uma tecnologia para outra, ou mesmo achar algo semelhante na tecnologia já usava.

Esse último ponto é importante porque muitas vezes a escolha é feita só porque a pessoa que a fez não conhece outras coisas que vão dar o mesmo resultado na tecnologia que ele já usa.

Também há mudanças político-sociais nas equipes que podem dirigir as escolhas. Muitas pessoas dizem que tem que *escolher a ferramenta certa para o problema*, mas na prática as decisões ocorrem mais baseado em *a melhor ferramenta é aquele que você conhece*. O que não é de todo ruim, em geral dá melhor resultado usar algo que domina mesmo que não seja o mais adequado. Desde que não haja exageros. O problema é quando a equipe não sabe usar corretamente nenhuma tecnologia. Pior ainda quando acredita saber e não ser verdade. É claro que a mudança pode ser só porque a ferramenta era mais correta.

Fora isso tem gosto também. Você não tem ideia de quantas decisões são tomadas sem base em critério técnico, ou baseado em falsas premissas.

Linguagens de programação são capazes de fazer tudo o que precisa. É só uma questão de adequação e só analisando casos concretos para tentar responder adequadamente. Fora o fato de achar que ambos são linguagens, sua observação de que são quase a mesma coisa está correta. Ambas devem atender razoavelmente bem qualquer projeto e ambas vão trazer alguns desafios.

No geral o que dá para dizer é isto. Claro que cada caso pode ter um motivo diferente e alguns são bem fundamentados. Mas a maiorias das decisões tem um pouco de arbitrariedade ou pelo menos motivações não técnicas, quando não é por modismo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Caso da google: "Python where we can, C++ where we must". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560310/heavy-usage-of-python-at-google/2561008. Neste caso é mesmo porque vêm utilidade nas duas, não querem abdicar de nenhuma delas

Comment: @Miguel até porque elas possuem realmente objetivos bem diferentes e eles possuem cabeças muito boas para decidir o quando é *must*. Ainda que possa errar também.

Comment: sim, creio que a chave para fazer isso é ter de haver uma excelente/sábia gestão do software, senão mais vale ficarmo-nos só por uma linguagem certo?

Comment: @Miguel acredito que sim na maioria dos casos, mas se tiver que usar mais que uma, acho que elas precisam ser bem díspares.