# Como utilizar mais de uma linguagem de programação no backend?

Tags: lógica

Eu gostaria de uma explicação detalhada(ou simples, se for fácil de entender) de como as empresas usam mais de uma linguagem de programação no backend.
Como é estabelecida a comunicação entre as linguagens?

Por exemplo:
Temos diversos artigos na internet falando sobre o Twitter usar Python, Go, etc, mas como é feita a comunicação entre as linguagens + frontend?

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175893/por-que-utilizar-duas-linguagens-server-side-no-mesmo-sistema/175901?noredirect=1#comment362876_175901. Bem-vindo ao SOPT, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Depende muito, é feita da forma que for mais adequada possível para o problema. Há casos que simplesmente pode ser compilado junto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem várias forma de comunicar serviços diferentes escritos em linguagens diferentes, vou listar algumas que pensei agora:

- Fila (protocolo AMQP, servidores como o RabbitMQ, um publica na fila e outro escuta)
- HTTP (JSON, XML, form data, x-www-form-urlencoded, etc.)
- Banco de dados (forma menos recomendada, um serviço escreve num banco e outro lê).

Geralmente o frontend se comunica via HTTP com o backend, e hoje em dia, com o crescimento das SPAs, REST via JSON tem sido a forma preferida de comunicar frontend com backend.