# Como gravar valores no banco de dados MySQL usando PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados que criei no MYSQL com a tabela chamada `publicacoes`. Essa tabela tem os campos `id`, `titulo`, `conteudo` e `data_publicacao`. Gostaria de saber como faço para inserir valores nessa tabela usando o PHP.

Eu já tenho um formulário que contém os campos `titulo` e `conteudo`, mas como eu faria pra registrá-los na minha tabela?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>nova publicação</h2>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Título" name="titulo">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Conteúdo" name="conteudo" row='3'></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

O meu banco de dados tem o nome de  `blog`, mas como é possível conectar o PHP com o banco?

Já ouvi falar que tem que usar `PDO` ou as funções do Mysql do PHP, mas poderiam me dar um pequeno exemplo?

> **Nota**: percebi que há muitos usuários que não sabem fazer isso inicialmente e também não consegui encontrar nenhuma pergunta nesse sentido no site, por isso tomei a inciativa de fazê-la.

Comment: Eu não sei se posso postar links mas existe esse tutorial no youtube que explica muito bem como fazer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etRFu_eJ3vU

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Resposta curta: não tem. Precisa ler tudo mesmo.

## TL;DR

Para compreender bem o processo por completo será necessário entender vários conceitos básicos que muitos usuários iniciantes pecam em não estudá-los. Muitos dos erros cometidos ocorrem justamente porque o usuário não tem domínio pleno sobre aquilo que está acontecendo, apenas replicando códigos que encontrou em diversas fontes, seja no Stack Overflow, seja na documentação oficial da linguagem, seja em sites quaisquer.

Os conceitos abordados são:

1. Quem é cliente e quem é servidor?
2. O que é HTTP?

   - Construindo a requisição HTTP com o formulário
   - Apache e a requisição HTTP
3. E o banco de dados?

   - Conectando com o banco de dados
   - Inserindo os dados no banco de dados

A pergunta foca na utilização da linguagem PHP no lado do servidor, mas todos os **conceitos** que serão abordados na resposta valerão para qualquer linguagem; apenas os códigos propriamente ditos que mudarão.

## 1) Quem é cliente e quem é servidor?

Para facilitar a resposta, iremos reduzir nosso domínio apenas para uma comunicação entre navegador e servidor, que é a mais simples e a mais comum, não entrando em detalhes sobre requisições assíncronas a partir do JavaScript ou requisições feitas a partir do servidor, como quando utilizado cURL, por exemplo.

No âmbito de desenvolvimento Web, denominamos como **cliente** o navegador (*browser*) - e por **usuário** a pessoa que faz uso do navegador. A função no navegador é interpretar uma linguagem de marcação que é mais legível ao computador do que para humanos e renderizá-la de uma forma agradável aos humanos: o HTML. Todos os navegadores atualmente possuem também suporte à uma linguagem de programação dinâmica que permite criar páginas HTML com interação com o usuário: o JavaScript. E para completar, ainda existe o CSS que é uma linguagem de estilo que o navegador utiliza como referência para a renderização do HTML. Tudo isso ocorre no navegador, utilizando o computador do cliente, sem dependência alguma com o servidor. Chamamos isso de lado do cliente, ou em inglês, *client-side*.

O **servidor** é o computador que hospeda sua aplicação. É o local que o desenvolvedor comumente acessa via FTP para enviar os arquivos do site. Este computador possui um programa instalado que é chamado de **servidor web** que é responsável por gerenciar os pedidos dos clientes e fornecer aos mesmos uma resposta de acordo com o pedido, garantindo também que a resposta chegue ao devido cliente e não um cliente qualquer. Esse programa é o Apache, ou Nginx, ou análogos. Esse programa pode ser configurado para trabalhar com linguagens de porgramação, como o PHP, para tornar o processo de criação das resposta mais dinâmico - por isso que é necessário uma linguagem de programação para criar páginas dinâmicas. Basicamente o que o servidor web faz é executar o código escrito em PHP definindo alguns valores que indicam quem é o cliente e qual foi o pedido feito por este. Estes valores ficam disponíveis nas [variáveis super globais](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.superglobals.php) do PHP. Tudo o que acontece no Apache e no PHP nós dizemos que está no lado do servidor, ou em inglês, *server-side*.

**Leitura recomendada:**

- [Qual a diferença entre código client-side e server-side em desenvolvimento web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/608/5878)
- [Quais as diferenças entre client-side e server-side "rendering"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210359/quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-client-side-e-server-side-rendering)
- [Por que utilizar duas linguagens server-side no mesmo sistema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175893/por-que-utilizar-duas-linguagens-server-side-no-mesmo-sistema)

Desenvolvimento voltado ao lado do cliente é denominado **front-end** e desenvolvimento voltado ao lado do servidor é denominado **back-end**.

**Leitura recomendada:**

- [O que é Front-end e Back-end?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105495/5878)

## 2) O que é HTTP?

A Web funciona como um jogo de perguntas e respostas: um pergunta e o outro responde. No âmbito que estamos tratando, da conversa entre navegador e servidor, o navegador fará a pergunta e o servidor responderá. O nome correto desta pergunta é **requisição** e o nome correto desta resposta é **resposta** mesmo (hehe). E o qual a relação do HTTP com a requisição e a resposta? O HTTP é o idioma desta conversa. Se um fizer a pergunta em um idioma e o outro responder em um idioma diferente, concorda que a comunicação não pode ser estabelecida? Um não entenderá o outro. Mas se utilizarem o mesmo idioma, ambos se entenderão e é isso que o HTTP faz. Tecnicamente, chamamos o HTTP de protocolo de comunicação e ele é o meio utilizado por **qualquer** comunicação feita entre o cliente e o servidor.

- Para o navegador abrir uma página ele envia uma requisição HTTP para o servidor;
- Para o navegador enviar dados do formulário para o PHP ele envia através de uma requisição HTTP para o servidor;
- Para o navegador exibir os detalhes de um filme do banco de dados ele envia uma requisição HTTP para o servidor;
- Para o cliente atualizar os dados no banco de dados através de um formulário é enviado através de uma requisição HTTP para o servidor;

Mas como eu faço para enviar essa requisição HTTP a partir do navegador? Bom, de certa forma esse é o trabalho do próprio navegador. Por exemplo, quando você cria um link na sua página, você está informando ao navegador que ele precisará fazer uma requisição HTTP ao servidor que hospeda a página do link utilizando o método GET. A resposta por parte do servidor desta requisição será uma resposta HTTP com um código HTML no seu corpo e é esse código HTML que será renderizado quando o navegador muda de página. Nestes casos, a comunicação HTTP ocorre "por baixo dos panos" e o usuário nem percebe. Já quando a requisição HTTP partirá de um formulário, seja ele para cadastrar informações ou apenas para atualizá-las, a requisição HTTP será construída no elemento `form`. O atributo `action` definirá qual é a URL para o qual a requisição HTTP será enviada; o atributo `method` define qual será o método HTTP a ser utilizado na requisição. Lembra que antes eu comentei que o servidor web fornece algumas informações para o PHP através das super glbais? São exatamente essas informações. O que o Apache faz é analisar a requisição HTTP que chegou, extraindo essas informações e passar ao PHP para que ele decida qual será a melhor resposta a ser enviada de volta ao cliente.

### 2.1) Construindo a requisição HTTP com o formulário

A pergunta define o contexto de cadastro de uma publicação em um blog. Para isso, precisamos definir alguns pontos:

- Qual será a URL que tratará os dados e efetuará o cadastro no banco de dados?
- Quais serão os campos que o usuário deverá preencher?
- Qual é o método HTTP a ser utilizado?

**Qual será a URL que tratará os dados e efetuará o cadastro no banco de dados?**

Depende muito de como é projetado a aplicação, então a título de exemplo irei definir que é um arquivo chamado `cadastrar_post.php` localizado no diretório raiz da aplicação, então a URL será: `/cadastrar_post.php`. Com isso, definimos o valor do atributo `action` do nosso fomulário:

```
<form action="/cadastrar_post.php">
  ...
</form>
```

**Quais serão os campos que o usuário deverá preencher?**

Isso já foi respondido na pergunta e são os campos título e conteúdo. O primeiro sendo um texto curto e o segundo podendo ser um texto longo. Assim, podemos criar os campos assim como também foi apresentado na pergunta:

```
<form action="/cadastrar_post.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Título" name="titulo">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Conteúdo" name="conteudo" row='3'></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Qual é o método HTTP a ser utilizado?**

Na especificação HTTP recomenda-se utilizar o método `POST` quando o cliente envia dados novo ao servidor. Portanto, utilizaremos o método `POST`, definindo, assim, o valor do atributo `method` do formulário:

```
<form action="/cadastrar_post.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Título" name="titulo">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Conteúdo" name="conteudo" row='3'></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Quando submetido, o navegador enviará ao servidor uma requisição HTTP semelhante:

```
POST /cadastrar_post.php HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) ...

titulo={titulo}&conteudo={conteudo}
```

Onde `{titulo}` e `{conteudo}` são os valores informados no formulário.

### 2.2) Apache e a requisição HTTP

A mesma requisição acima é tratada pelo Apache no lado do servidor, passando ao PHP, através das variáveis super globais, as informações sobre tal requisição. Por exemplo, no PHP, caso o desenvolvedor precise verificar qual foi o método HTTP utilizado, basta acessar o valor em `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` e os valores informados pelo usuário no formulário estariam disponíveis em `$_POST["titulo"]` e `$_POST["conteudo"]`, assim o PHP terá ferramentas suficientes para decidir o que fazer com as informações recebidas e, mais importante que isso, indicar ao Apache qual deverá ser a resposta que será entregue ao cliente de volta. O Apache irá analisar essas informações passadas pelo PHP e gerará a resposta HTTP que enviará ao navegador.

> Para validações de dados vindo pela HTTP, você pode utilizar a função [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php).

Supondo que a página PHP fosse algo como:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    echo "<h1>" . $_POST["titulo"] . "</h1>";
    echo "<p>" . $_POST["conteudo"] . "</p>";

}
```

A resposta HTTP que seria gerada seria parecida com:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/1.3.27 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 34

<h1>{titulo}</h1>
<p>{conteudo}</p>
```

O navegador, recebendo esta resposta, irá analisá-la e exibir o código HTML. Perceba que o código PHP não faz parte da resposta HTTP; ele é utilizado apenas para gerar a resposta. O navegador não tem acesso ao código PHP e é por isso que quando é necessário fazer alguma interação no lado do cliente é necessário utilizar JavaScript e não mais PHP.

**Leitura recomendada:**

- [Quais as diferenças entre HTTP 1.1 vs HTTP 1.0?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153512/5878)
- [Quais as vantagens de se utilizar os métodos HTTP corretos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49322/5878)
- [Como o protocolo HTTP processa as requisições?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174116/5878)
- [Em que linguagem o HTTP foi escrito quando implementado na Web?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177519/5878)

## 3) E o banco de dados?

Agora que sabemos exatamente como o cliente e o servidor se comunicam podemos nos preocupar em desenvolver as regras da aplicação. Em PHP existe inúmeras formas de se trabalhar com banco de dados. Dependerá principalmente de qual banco de dados está trabalhando. Como especificado na pergunta, o banco de dados será o MySQL e para tal o PHP já possui uma API nativa: a [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php). Esta API te permite tanto utilizar a [forma procedural quanto a orientada a objetos](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php). Nesta resposta eu focarei a atenção no uso procedural, pois não vejo necessidade de utilizar a orientado a objetos senão junto com uma aplicação que utilize o mesmo paradigma.

### 3.1) Conectando com o banco de dados

Para efetuar a conexão com o banco de dados, utilizamos a função [`mysqli_connect`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysqli-connect.php), que recebe como parâmetros:

1. **host**: nome do servidor do banco de dados;
2. **username**: nome do usuário de acesso ao banco;
3. **password**: senha do usuário de acesso ao banco;
4. **dbname**: nome do banco de dados;

Há outros dois parâmetros que são menos utilizados e estão descritos na documentação oficial. Além disso, todos os parâmetros são opcionais.

Assim, para fazer a conexão ao servidor local, podemos fazer:

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "blog");
```

Porém, fazer apenas isso não garante que a conexão seja efetuada com sucesso. Para tratar possíveis erros, basta utilizar as funções [`mysqli_connect_errno`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.connect-errno.php) e [`mysqli_connect_error`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.connect-error.php).

```
<?php

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "blog");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {

    http_response_code(500);

    die("Falha ao conectar com o banco de dados: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}
```

Se a conexão falhar, a execução é interrompida, exibindo a mensagem de erro na tela. Se tudo ocorrer com sucesso, a execução continua.

> **Nota:** é utilizado a função [`http_response_code`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.http-response-code.php) para definir o código da resposta HTTP que o servidor deverá entregar ao cliente, pois, visto que ocorreu algum erro na conexão, é necessário informar o cliente de que a requisição que ele fez falhou.

### 3.2) Inserindo os dados no banco de dados

O comando SQL a ser executado aqui dependerá da estrutura da tabela no banco de dados. Dado na pergunta que existem as colunas: `id`, `titulo`, `conteudo` e `data_publicacao` irei fazer as seguintes considerações:

1. Coluna `id` é do tipo `int`, definida como chave primária e auto incremento;
2. Coluna `titulo` é do tipo `varchar(255)`, não nula;
3. Coluna `conteudo` é do tipo `text`, não nula;
4. Coluna `data_publicacao` é do tipo `timestamp`, definida como valor padrão `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`;

Desta forma, os valores de `id` e `data_publicacao` serão definidos automaticamente pelo banco de dados, deixando para nos preocuparmos apenas com `titulo` e `conteudo` (exatamente os valores que recebemos via POST).

Desta forma, podemos preparar o comando SQL a ser executado:

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `publicacoes`(`titulo`, `conteudo`) VALUES (?, ?)")) {

} else {

    http_response_code(500);

    die("Falha ao preparar o comando SQL: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));

}
```

Para substituir devidamente os caracteres `?` por seus respectivos valores, utilizamos [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `publicacoes` VALUES (?, ?)")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $_POST['titulo'], $_POST['conteudo']);

} else {

    http_response_code(500);

    die("Falha ao preparar o comando SQL: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));

}
```

Por fim, executamos o comando com [`mysqli_stmt_execute`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.execute.php):

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `publicacoes` VALUES (?, ?)")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['titulo']);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['conteudo']);

    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {

        http_response_code(200);

        echo "Cadastro realizado com sucesso.";

    } else {

        http_response_code(500);

        echo "Ooops! Algo de errado não está certo: " . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);

    }

} else {

    http_response_code(500);

    echo "Falha ao preparar o comando SQL: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);

}
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

- [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/5878)
- [PDO e mysqli são as únicas opções para trabalhar com banco de dados em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219396/5878)
- [PHP somente se conecta com o MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215074/5878)
- [Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/5878)
- [MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/5878)

---

Um possível código PHP para tratar, então, deste cadastro, seria:

```
<?php

// Código padrão da resposta HTTP:
$httpResponseCode = 200;

// Mensagem padrão a ser exibida na tela:
$message = "Yaaay! Seu cadastro realizado com sucesso xD";

// Verifica se o método da requisição é POST:
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_POST["titulo"] && !empty($_POST["conteudo"]))) {

    // É POST, então tenta conectar com o banco de dados:
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sopt");

    // Verifica se a conexão foi realizada com sucesso:
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {

        // Não, então emite a resposta HTTP 500 Internal Server Error:
        $httpResponseCode = 500;
        $message = "Falha ao conectar com o banco de dados: " . mysqli_connect_error();

    } else {

        // A conexão foi estabelecida, então prepara o comando SQL, verificando se ocorreu erro:
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `publicacoes`(`titulo`, `conteudo`) VALUES (?, ?)")) {

            // Sem erros, então substitui os valores dos parâmetros no comando SQL:
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $_POST['titulo'], $_POST['conteudo']);

            // Executa o comando e verifica se ocorreu erro:
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {

                // Ocorreu algum erro, então emite a resposta HTTP 500 Internal Server Error:
                $httpResponseCode = 500;
                $message = "Ooops! Algo de errado não está certo: " . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);

            }

        } else {

            // O comando preparado parece estar errado, então emite a resposta HTTP 500 Internal Server Error:
            $httpResponseCode = 500;
            $message = "Falha ao preparar o comando SQL: " . mysqli_error($mysqli);

        }

    }

} else {

    // Não é POST, então emite a resposta HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed:
    $httpResponseCode = 405;
    $message = "Ooops! Eu só aceito o método POST e não gosto de valores vazios.";

}

// Diz ao Apache qual será o código HTTP da resposta:
http_response_code($httpResponseCode);

// Exibe a mensagem na tela:
echo $message;
```

Comment: Cara, sensacional. É sempre interessante existir respostas grandes em contraste com outras menores. Acho que acaba sendo benéfico de todas as formas

Answer (score 9):

As libs atuais para conectar no MySQL são o PDO e o MySQL**i**.

O MySQLi permite dois tipos de manipulação uma orientada a objeto e outra baseada em funções (como a antiga e obsoleta mysql_*).

#### 1 - Criar a conexão

O primeiro passo é criara conexão isso é feito com a função `mysqli_connect()` é necessário informar três argumentos, o primeiro é o servidor, seguido do usuário, senha e opcionalmente o quarto é o nome do banco de dados.

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'nome_do_banco');
```

Outra forma seria chamar `mysqli_select_db()` depois da conexão, ela é responsável por selecionar ou trocar o banco de dados associada a conexão.

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha');
mysqli_select_db($conexao, 'banco_novo');
```

#### 2 - Enviar uma consulta ao banco

Lembre sempre de sanitizar as entradas enviadas pelo usuário antes de enviar uma consulta para o banco. Existem duas formas de fazer isso uma escapando as entradas com `mysqli_real_escape_string()` e a outra com prepared statements.

#### 2.1

```
//código da conexão
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO publicacoes (titulo, conteudo, data_publicacao) VALUES('%s', '%s', now())", mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['titulo']), mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['conteudo']));
if(!mysqli_query($conexao, $sql)){
   echo 'erro: '. mysqli_error($conexao);
}else{
   echo 'sucesso, linhas incluidas/afetadas: '. mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);
}
```

Esse código escapa as entradas do usuário (`$_POST`) com `mysqli_real_escape_string()` e atribui os valores em `$sql`. `mysqli_query()` é responsável por executar a consulta enviada e sempre retornar um boolean sinalizado se a operação ocorreu com sucesso ou não.

Quando um erro acontecer pegue a mensagem de erro que o banco enviou com a função `mysqli_error()`.

Para DML (insert, update e delete) alguma vezes é interessante saber quantas linhas foram incluidas/modificadas/removidas, no bloco `else` a função `mysqli_affected_rows()` fornece essa informação, nesse exemplo o resulta sempre será um.

#### 2.2

Algumas vantagens de utilizar prepared statments são:

- O fato de enviar a consulta e os valores de forma seperada.
- Melhor organização da consulta pela ausência de aspas simples nos valores.
- Consultas que são executadas com frequência tiram vantagem por serem 'compiladas' pelo banco, basicamente a mesma instrução é executada N vezes e o que vai mudar são os valores.

Para DML são necessários dois passos a definição da consulta e posteriormente o bind (ligação) que a indicação de qual valor um argumento/plache holder (a interrogação) irá assumir.

```
//código da conexão
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao, "INSERT INTO publicacoes (titulo, conteudo, data_publicacao) VALUES(?, ?, now()");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $_POST['titulo'], $_POST['conteudo']);
if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
    echo 'erro: '. mysqli_stmt_error($conexao); 
}
```

Comment: A ordem das colunas com os respectivos values não tem importancia?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo é baseado na posição, a primeira interrogação vai assumir o valor de `$_POST['titulo']` e assim vai.

Comment: me refiro a do item 2.1

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo também é baseado na posição.

Answer (score 5):

Precisa de uma conexão com o banco de dados:

conexao.php

```
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';//Teu servidor
$usuario = 'root';//Teu usuário do Mysql
$senha = '';//Tua senha se houver
$banco = 'blog';//Teu banco
$con = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);//A conexão
if($con->connect_error)
{   die("Connection failed: ".$con->connect_error);//Se teve erro mostra
} 
?>
```

Agora precisa pegar as informações do formulário e inserir no banco de dados:

action_page.php

```
<?php
include 'conexao.php';//Inclui a conexao

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];//Atribui o valor do campo com o name titulo a variavel
$conteudo = $_POST['conteudo'];//Atribui o valor do campo com o name conteudo a variavel

$sql = "INSERT INTO publicacoes (titulo,conteudo,data_publicacao) VALUES ('$titulo','$conteudo',NOW( ))";//Monta a query para inserção no bd
$con->query($sql);//Executa a query
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Antes de mais nada, corrija o seu HTML pois do jeito que seu form está não vai inserir os dados na sua tabela do banco. Informe o method** Exemplo: `<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">`

Configure a coluna `data_publicacao` para o tipo TIMESTAMP na sua tabela do banco de dados e coloque no valor Default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

> Definimos na coluna `data_publicacao` um DEFAULT `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` para quando recebermos um valor NULL, o próprio SGBD insira neste campo a data/hora atual.

<sup>Detalhe, cada valor dessa coluna consumirá apenas 4 bytes, enquanto que se tivéssemos o tipo DATETIME, consumiria 8 bytes.</sup>

**PHP**

```
//Abre uma conexão com um servidor MySQL
$conn = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "blog");

//Recupera os valores enviados do formulario
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$conteudo = $_POST['conteudo'];

//insere dados no banco
$squery = "INSERT INTO publicacoes (titulo, conteudo) VALUES('$titulo','$conteudo')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$squery);


if($resultado === false){
   // Caso algo tenha dado errado, exibe uma mensagem de erro   
   echo 'erro: '. mysqli_error($conn);
}else{
   // Aviso de registro criado com sucesso
   echo 'Operação realizada com sucesso';
}

//fecha conexão
mysqli_close($conn);
```

> Acho que dessa forma fica mais fácil para quem está iniciando.