# Alterar informações da página com PHP

Tags: php, html

Estou fazendo um trabalho da Faculdade e nele preciso alterar informações da página como **título-intro**, **blockquote** e o **cite** da página abaixo, mas tem que ser feito através de uma outra página como se fosse uma página administrativa a única ideia que tive foi através de formulário e utilizando o método POST, mas parece não ser a forma correta, como posso fazer isso de uma forma correta e simples?

Arquivo `adm.php`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <form method="post" action="index.php">
       <input type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Digite o novo título">
        <input type="submit" value="Alterar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu arquivo index que preciso alterar `index.php`

```
<?php

    $titulo = $_POST["titulo"];

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site com PHP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="intro">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="titulo-intro"><?php echo $titulo ?></h1>
            <blockquote class="quote">"não tenha nada em sua casa que você não considere útil ou acredita ser bonito"</blockquote>
            <cite>Willian Morris</cite>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

E o CSS

```
body {
    background: #444;
}
.intro {
    color: #FFF;
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg);
    height: 380px;
    text-align: center;
}
.titulo-intro {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.quote {
    width: 32%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
}

.quote::before, .quote::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 60px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta me parece ser bem ampla. A ideia é você salvar esses dados no banco de dados. Daí, através de um parâmetro `$_GET`, você pega o `id` do que foi salvo na tabela e traz os resultados para  a página.

Comment: "mas parece não ser a forma correta", por quê?

Comment: Eu acho que um bom lugar pra começar é [Como gravar valores no banco de dados Mysql com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219812/como-gravar-valores-no-banco-de-dados-mysql-usando-php)

Comment: Não faz sentido fazer o que você está fazendo através do POST. Você quer que o admin publique algo, e isso reflita no script PHP, como um template, que contém os mesmos estilos, porém só varia os dados. Eu acho que precisaria no mínimo de um dB aí.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters obrigado pela resposta, também não vejo outra alternativa a não sei usar um dB simples aqui. Valeu mesmo, o link me ajudou bastante.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A maneira correta, a primeira vista, seria com requisições AJAX.
Terias um fonte um JS fazendo requisições pra essa outra página em PHP, capturando os valores e atualizando-os.

```
function ajax() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "OUTRA-PAGINA.PHP", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```