# Como enviar informações de um formulário em html para um array no php?

Tags: php, html, array, formulário

Eu criei um formulário de contato em HTML:

```html
<section id="formulario">
<form action="assets/php/script.php" id="quaform" method="post">

<p class="textform">Nome Completo:</p>
    <div class="testeform"><input type="text" name="nome" size="50"></div><br>
<p>Email:</p>
    <div class="testeform"><input type="email" name="email" size="50"></div><br>
<p>Assunto:</p>
    <div class="testeform"><input type="text" name="assunto" size="50"></div><br>
<p>Mensagem:</p>
    <div class="testeform"><textarea id="caixademsg" name="msg"></textarea></div><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="submitbutton">

</form>
</section>
```

E consigo enviar as informações de quando preencho o form desse jeito:

```html
<?php
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$assunto = $_POST["assunto"];
$msg = $_POST["msg"];

$cont = 1;
$notas = array(
    'Nome' => $nome,
    'Email' => $email,
    'Assunto' => $assunto,
    'Mensagem' => $msg,
);

foreach ($notas as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: ","<br>","$value","<br>";
}

?>
```

O que eu quero realmente, é quando eu enviar 1 form, ele ficar salvo numa página, onde eu possa ver ele depois, se eu enviar 10 forms diferentes, ter os 10 forms nessa pagina pra eu poder ver quando eu quiser.

Comment: Para você poder ver quando quiser acho que será necessário uma base de dados

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como gravar valores no banco de dados MySQL usando PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219812/como-gravar-valores-no-banco-de-dados-mysql-usando-php)