# como salvo o form no banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde a todos estou com problema para salvar no banco de dados, tenho o codigo de conexão em php certinho e do form em html mas não sei como posso unir eles para salvar esse <form tem <select, <input e <option e <div porem tentei alguns códigos e retornam variável vazia não sei o que fazer agradeço desde já a ajuda sou novo em programação.

Meu formulário

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contato</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Mudarestado(el) {
            var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
            if (display == "none")
                document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
            else
                document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id="divescolhas">
            <div id="acompanhamentos">
                <button id="acomp" style="background-color: #2c868f;">
                    <a style="width:100%;color: black" href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i aria-hidden="true"></i>Acompanhamentos
                    </a>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="audiencias">
                <button id="aud" style="background-color: #2c868f;">
                    <a style="width:100%;color: black" href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i aria-hidden="true"></i>Audiências
                    </a>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!--inicio div copias-->
            <div id="copias" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                <button id="cop" style="background-color: #2c868f;" onclick="Mudarestado('minhaDiv')">
                    <a style="width:100%;color: black;" href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i aria-hidden="true"></i>Cópias
                    </a>
                </button>
                <div id="minhaDiv" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                    <div id="tipocopias">
                        <label>Tipo de Cópia *</label>
                        <select id="copiastipo" name="copiastipo">
                            <option value=""method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Selecione</option>
                            <option value="despacho"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Despacho do Juiz</option>
                            <option value="embargos"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Embargos de Execução</option>
                            <option value="inicial"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Inicial de Processo</option>
                            <option value="parcial"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Parcial</option>
                            <option value="processo"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Processo Integral</option>
                            <option value="recursos"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Recursos</option>
                            <option value="ultimos"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Últimos Andamentos</option>

                    </div>
                    </select>
                    <div id="quantiacopias" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                        <label>Quantidade aproximada de páginas *</label>
                        <input id="copiasquantia" type="text" placeholder="Quantidade" name="copiasquantia" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                    </div>
                    <div id="formcopias" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                        <label>Formato das Cópias *</label>
                        <select id="copiasform" name="copiasform" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                            <option value=""method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Selecione</option>
                            <option value="legivel"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Foto Legível</option>
                            <option value="impresso"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Impresso</option>
                            <option value="pdf"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Digitalizado em PDF</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div id="copiaReembolsa" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                        <label>Reembolsa custo com Cópias? *</label>
                        <select id="reenbolsacopia" name="reenbolsacopia" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                            <option value=""method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Selecione</option>
                            <option value="s"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Sim</option>
                            <option value="n"method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">Não</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div id="PrazoLim" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                        <label>Prazo limite*</label>
                        <input id="prazo" type="text" placeholder="Data" style="width:120px" name="prazo" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                        <input id="prazoHora" type="text" placeholder="Hora" style="width:120px" name="prazoHora" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                    </div>

                    <div id="Procesnum" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                        <label>Número do Processo</label>
                        <input name="numProces" id="numProces" size="40px" type="text" placeholder="Informe o número do processo..." method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                    </div>
                    <div id="Proftipo">
                        <label>Tipo de profissional necessário *</label>
                        <select id="tipoProf" name="tipoProf" method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
                            <option value="">Selecione</option>
                            <option value="ap">Advogado e Preposto</option>
                            <option value="a">Somente Advogado</option>
                            <option value="p">Somente Preposto</option>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--fim div copias-->

            <!--inicio div distribuicao-->
            <div id="distribuicao">
                <button id="distri" style="background-color: #2c868f;">
                    <a style="width:100%;color: black" href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i aria-hidden="true"></i>Distribuição
                    </a>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="protocolos">
                <button id="proto">
                    <a style="width:100%;color: black" href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i aria-hidden="true"></i>Protocolos
                    </a>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="btnoutros">
                <button style="background-color: #2c868f;">
                    <a style="width: 100%; color:black;" href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i aria-hidden="true"></i> Outros Serviços
                    </a>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--dados de pedido-->
        <form method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
            <div id="divpedido">

                <div id="divoutros">
                    <input id="Cidade" value="7862" type="hidden" />
                    <input id="nomecidade" value="" type="hidden" />
                    <label>Tipo do Serviço *</label>
                    <select id="outros">
                        <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <option value="alvaras">Alvarás</option>
                        <option value="analises">Análises</option>
                        <option value="andamentos">Andamentos</option>
                        <option value="buscas">Buscas e Apreensões</option>
                        <option value="cargas">Cargas</option>
                        <option value="certidoes">Certidões</option>
                        <option value="despachos">Despachos</option>
                        <option value="pecas">Elaboração de Peças</option>
                        <option value="tese">Elaboração de Tese</option>
                        <option value="exame">Exame de Processos</option>
                        <option value="guias">Guias</option>
                        <option value="mandados">Mandados</option>
                        <option value="sustentacoes">Sustentações Orais</option>
                        <option value="outros">Outros Serviços</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div id="servlocal">
                    <label>Local do serviço *</label>
                    <input id="localserv" type="text" size="40px" placeholder="Informe o local do serviço...">
                </div>

                <div id="Areacbo">
                    <label>Área *</label>
                    <select id="cboArea">
                        <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <option value="trabalhista">Trabalhista</option>
                        <option value="civel">Cível</option>
                        <option value="criminal">Criminal</option>
                        <option value="outra">Outra</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div id="tipoaud">
                    <label>Tipo de Audiência *</label>
                    <select id="tipo">
                        <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <option value="conciliacao">Conciliação</option>
                        <option value="julgamento">Julgamento</option>
                        <option value="instrucao">Instrução</option>
                        <option value="instr_julg">Instrução e Julgamento</option>
                        <option value="una">Una</option>
                        <option value="outro">Outro</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div id="PrazoLim">
                    <label>Prazo limite*</label>
                    <input id="prazo" type="text" placeholder="Data" style="width:120px">
                    <input id="prazoHora" type="text" placeholder="Hora" style="width:120px">
                </div>

                <div id="AudData">
                    <label>Data audiência *</label>
                    <input id="DataAud" type="text" placeholder="Data" style="width: 120px;">
                    <input id="HoraAud" type="text" placeholder="Hora" style="width: 120px;">
                </div>

                <div id="Procesnum">
                    <label>Número do Processo</label>
                    <input id="numProces" size="40px" type="text" placeholder="Informe o número do processo...">
                </div>

                <div id="Procestipo">
                    <label>Tipo de Processo*</label>
                    <select id="tipoProces">
                        <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <option value="d">Digital</option>
                        <option value="f">Físico</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div id="Proftipo">
                    <label>Tipo de profissional necessário *</label>
                    <select id="tipoProf">
                        <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <option value="ap">Advogado e Preposto</option>
                        <option value="a">Somente Advogado</option>
                        <option value="p">Somente Preposto</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div id="Profcertificado">
                    <label>Profissional com Certificado Digital?</label>
                    <select id="certificadoProf">
                        <option value="">Selecione</option>
                        <option value="s">Sim</option>
                        <option value="n">Indiferente</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <form method="POST" action="salva_mensagem.php">
            <label>Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo" required></br></br>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Seu melho e-mail" required></br></br>
            <label>Telefone de Contato:</label>
            <input type="text" name="fone" placeholder="Telefone de Contato" required></br></br>
            <label>Mensagem:</label>
            <textarea name="mensagem"></textarea></br></br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar Demandas">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Conexao

```php
<?php
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $dbname = "testeform";
    
    //Criar a conexão
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
```

e as variaveis

```php
<?php
    include_once('conexao.php');
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $fone = $_POST['fone'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
    $copiastipo = $_POST['copiastipo'];
    $copiasquantia = $_POST['copiasquantia'];
    $copiasform = $_POST['copiasform'];
    $reenbolsacopia = $_POST['reenbolsacopia'];
    $numproces = $_POST['numproces'];
    $tipoprof = $_POST['tipoprof'];

    $result_msg_contato = "INSERT INTO form_demandas(nome, email, fone, mensagem, copiastipo, copiasquantia, copiasform, reenbolsacopia, numproces, tipoprof , created) 
    VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$fone', '$mensagem', '$copiastipo','$copiasquantia','$copiasform','$reenbolsacopia','$reenbolsacopia','$numproces','$tipoprof', NOW())";
    $resultado_msg_contato= mysqli_query($conn, $result_msg_contato);
```

Comment: Por que `'$reenbolsacopia'` é passada duas vezes no seu INSERT?

Comment: foi sem querer duas vezes mas corrigi e assim mesmo da vazia

Comment: Por algum motivo especial que nenhum dos seus campos no HTML possui o atributo `name` definido?

Comment: definidos? eu coloquei eles em todos os inputs selects

Comment: Existem diversos `<input>` e `<select>` que não pertencem a um `<form>`; há um `<form>` que possui vários campos, nenhum com o atributo `name` definido; por fim, há outro `<form>` que envia para o mesmo arquivo apenas poucos campos. Não sei bem o que você tentou fazer, mas claramente não compreendeu o básico de formulários no HTML ainda. Recomendo revisar o conteúdo antes de continuar. Uma referência muito boa é a documentação no MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Sugiro a leitura também de [Como gravar valores no banco de dados MySQL usando PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219812/5878) para ter um overview de tudo o que acontece.

Comment: Obrigado vou dar uma lida mas pelo que voce falou precisa estar tudo dentro de um form só nao pode ser mais de um?